# Custom TYPO3 extension not saving fields correctly

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a custom extension, it is irrelevant what it's about, but for the record it is used to display attractions in a certain area. My problem is, when the editor adds one attraction in the backend, the title field is not saved in some cases. There is no pattern to it, I have tested with over 60 records. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a [known bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80672) that only affects Google Chrome. I Couldn't reproduce it with latest Chrome (58.x) though.

So I assume the Editor uses Google Chrome and has yet to update it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am waiting for feedback from my customer. I also have an older version of chrome. I will test this with other browsers, and accept your answer if it solves my problem.